# Finding extrema of function of three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

So i have to study this function and find out if there are any local or absolute extrema :

$ f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} :$

$$ f(x,y,z)=2-\left(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + \left(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^3 $$

I've read that, for 3 or more variable functions, if the Hessian is positive definite at a certain point then f has a minimum and if it's negative it has a maximum, but how do i see if it's positive/negative definite at that point?

Comment: Because your Hessian will be a Hermitian matrix you can use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: have you get the derivatives?

Comment: @Adolfo Do you know if there is any other way of solving this problem without using matrices? And thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoãoBarbosa Why don't you want to use Adolfo's method. Aren't you familiar with the properties of hermitian matrices? or your teacher has told not to use matrices?

Comment: @sepideh Well this problem showed up in the multivariable calculus chapter and i wasn't really introduced to the concept of hermitian matrices so i was thinking it could be solved without it

Comment: @JoãoBarbosa but you know for a continuous function the hessian matrix is always a hermitian one and being positive-definite or negative-definite is just defined for hermitian matrices. so in order to study about the extremas of a multi-variable function you should be familiar alittle with hermitian matrices. you don't need to know every thing about them but you should be able to say that whether a hermitian matrix is positive definite or negative definite. It's not a very difficult concept maybe the page [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) confused u

Comment: if you're not familiar with matrices and the concept eigen-value and eigen-vector I can learn you an easy way to detect whether the hessian matrix is positive-definite or negative-definite. I mean if you are not familiar, there's no need to be mixed up with the definition of principal minors and etc. just learn the trick of Sylvester's criterion

Comment: hint: try to find the local minima and maxima of $g(t) = 2 - t^2 + t^3$ first.

Comment: @sepideh ye the criterion is relatively easy to apply and i think i got it down! Thanks for all the help!